# Formal power series derivation question

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-power-series

Good day to you!

One can define a derivation $\frac{d}{dx}$ on the ring of formal power series by letting $\frac{d}{dx} (\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k x^k ) = \sum_{k \geq 0} k a_k x^{k-1} $. In this case, $\frac{d}{dx}(x) = 1$.

I'm wondering, is it possible to find another derivation $()^\prime$ which also results in $(x)^\prime = 1$?

How about considering the special case of the ring of formal power series over the rational numbers?

Comment: What properties do you want the derivative to satisfy? Must it coincide with the series' derivative for convergent series?

Comment: If your new "derivation" is linear and follows the product rule, then it is uniquely determined by $x'=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case $A=\Bbb{Q}[[x]]$ no this is the only one.

$D$ is a map $A\to A$ such that $D(a+b)=D(a)+D(b), D(ab)=aD(b)+bD(a)$

$D(x)=1$

This implies that $D(c_n x^n)=c_n n x^{n-1}$ for $c_n\in \Bbb{Q}$ so $D$ is the standard derivative on $\Bbb{Q}[x]$

Let $f=\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n x^n $

Write $f=\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n + x^{N+1} g_N$ then $$D(f)=D(\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n)+x^{N+1}D(g_N)+(N+1)x^N g_N= D(\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n)+O(x^N)$$
which implies that $$D(f)=\lim_{N\to \infty}D(\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n)+O(x^N)=\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n n x^{n-1}$$

Comment: Note that the answer may be different for $\Bbb{Q}((x))$ as $x^{N+1} D(g_N)$ doesn't have to  $\to 0$ anymore

Comment: If we did not use $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ but some general $R[[x]]$ where $D(r) = 0$ for $r \in R$, do you by any chance know if this would break uniqueness? Where does $\mathbb{Q}$ come into play?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ comes into play just to automatically get that $D(r)=0$ for all $r\in R$, so that $D(r x^n)=r n x^{n-1}$. For other rings there might be some derivations not satisfing this. @Nibbler

Comment: (Ah ok, because $\mathbb{Q}$ itself is the ring of constants, right?) So the conditions $D: R[[x]] \rightarrow R[[x]]$ derivation, $D(r) = 0$ for all $r \in R$ and $D(x) = 1$ are enough to say that the derivation is unique by just repeating your argument above?

Comment: Also, I'm not completely sure what $g_N$ is in the above consideration. (Why can we write $f$ as both an infinite sum and a finite one?)

Comment: @Nibbler obviously $g_N=\sum_{n\ge 0} c_{n+N+1} x^n$ no "finite sum"